# How to update/change tag values of classic EC2 instances using boto library

Tags: python, ubuntu, boto

I'm using boto library and able to get the tag values for my ec2 instances however, not able to update their values.

Could anyone please help with how to update/change tag values of classic EC2 instances using boto library?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the code you are using to collect them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding and removing tags on EC2 instances is quite easy in boto.  Let's say you have an instance with an ID of i-12345678 and you want to add the tag `foo=bar` to that instance.

```
import boto.ec2
c = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-2')
reservations = c.get_all_instances(instance_ids='i-12345678')
instance = reservations[0].instances[0]
instance.add_tag('foo', 'bar')
```

To remove the tag:

```
instance.remove_tag('foo', 'bar')
```

The second argument is the value of the tag and is optional.

Comment: so what I did is, to update the tag values deleted the tag first, get the desired tag name in place and add the tag again with that value.

Answer (score 2):

No you should not first delete and then add.

As the document says, `create_tags`,

> Adds or overwrites the specified tags for the specified Amazon EC2 resource or resources.

meaning essentially for both, you can further read about the function in [this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_tags) link.