# To update the 'key' name in dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, boto3, python-3.8

I have written a boto3 script to list the s3 buckets along with tagging information associated with it. My main intent is to filter the tag having keyword 'cost' in it. However I wanted to update any wrong key name ['cost_center', 'cost_Center', 'cost_Centre', 'costcentre', 'costcenter', 'costCentre', 'costCenter'] with 'cost_centre'. And also I want to keep the other tags along with updated `cost_centre` key.

Here is the code snippet:

```
import json
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

incorrect_tag = ['cost_center', 'cost_Center', 'cost_Centre', 'costcentre', 'costcenter', 'costCentre', 'costCenter']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client(service_name='s3')
    response = client.list_buckets()

    # list s3 buckets and the tags associated with the bucket
    for bucket in response['Buckets']:
        try:
            result = client.get_bucket_tagging(
                Bucket=bucket['Name']
                )
            value = result['TagSet']
            for tags in value:
                if 'cost' in tags['Key']:
                    print(f"The bucket name is: {bucket['Name']} and the tags are: {tags['Key']}:{tags['Value']}")
        except ClientError as e:
            if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'TagSetNotFoundError':
                print("TagSet Not Found Error" + e)
            else:
                print(f"The bucket name is: {bucket['Name']} has no tags")

    # replace wrong tag with the right tag key
    for bucket in response['Buckets']:
        if tags['Key'] in incorrect_tag:
            update_tag = client.put_bucket_tagging(
                Bucket=bucket['Name'],
                Tagging={
                    'TagSet': [
                        {
                            'Key': 'cost_centre',
                            'Value': tags['Value']
                        }
                    ]
                }
            )
```

Can someone please help me with the code to update the key 'cost_centre' without overriding the other tags attached to the S3 bucket.

Comment: Hi Arjun, is there any reason not to use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27842848/8658598 ?

Comment: can you tell me the issue with your current approach?

Comment: @deadshot, `overriding the other tags attached`.

Comment: @doneforaiur, my main intent is to target the tag 'cost_centre'. Also the S3 buckets belong to more than one team so I am not aware of whether they want to update any existing tags or not. Also the requirement is to check if `cost_centre` is there with the right semantics and if not it needs to be fixed. Hope it makes sense!

Comment: You can remove all the wrong tags without checking if they exist, then add the correct tag. Am I missing something?

Comment: @doneforaiur the tags are not homogeneous either in terms of number or values. I just need to concentrate on `cost_centre` tag and try to update the key for it in case there is a typo in its spelling. All other tags will be untouched.